# Retrieve data from cloudant database using java liberty(java servlet program)

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am facing problem:

Problem: Need to get the last value inserted in a table in cloudant database using java liberty (java servlet program). but I writea program which retrieve the data of a specific id.(code below)I need to get the last value inserted in cloudant database in an android application

```
@Resource(name = "couchdb/myCloudant")
protected CouchDbInstance mydb ;


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

     String dbname1 = "Tempdb";
     String dbname2 = "pulsedb";

   try {

    CouchDbConnector dbconnector1 = mydb.createConnector(dbname1, true);


            InputStream s1 = dbconnector1.getAsStream("2");
   // here passing the id 2 in cloudant this will return the document of id 2

            BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s1));
            StringBuilder out1 = new StringBuilder();
            String line1;
            while ((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
                out1.append(line1);
            }
           // response.getWriter().print();
            String ss1 = out1.toString();
   }
 }
```

[This the screenshot of table in cloudant database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ7Pi.png)

Comment: What do you mean, "get a program"?

Comment: Are you trying to get the last document id so you can increment it and that incremented value will be the next document id?  If so, that will not work with cloudant.  If you want atomically incrementing fields you will need to use another technology with cloudant such as redis.

Comment: No, I need to get the last value inserted in database to an android application

Answer (score 0):

To get the last document modified in the database you need to use the changes feed. You can find the documentation for the changes feed [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html).

You should also make use of the `since` query string parameter, so you don't read the entire changes feed on each request you make.

Comment: i need to get the last document using the Java liberty application in Bluemix(java servlet program) is it possible??

Comment: I'm not familiar with that application. But like I said. You can make a request to the changes feed. See the documentation for your chosen library to do this or make a raw HTTP request to make a call to the changes Feds.